# Delphi host for JavaFX applets

Tags: delphi, applet, javafx, java

I have created a NPAPI host for JavaFX applets in Delphi 2010. The host uses a private JRE to show the applet.  With Java 7 Update 10 it is possible to disable Java content in the browser.  I do not want this setting to disable the plugins in my host. Is it possible to override the deployment properties for my private JRE?